# BugSnag Laravel setFilter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, bugsnag

I am using BugSnag (version 1.*) and Laravel (version 4.1) and I cannot for the life of me figure out where to set setFilters (so that it hides entered password, credit card information, etc).

I've tried setting it under Bugsnag::setBeforeNotifyFunction, I've tried configuring it in the config.php for BugSnag. I see how to do it in the documentation, like this:

```
$bugsnag->setFilters(array('password', 'credit_card'));
```

but I have no idea how to do it with Laravel.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer.

All you have to do is in your app/start/global.php (or, some other globally loading location):

```
Bugsnag::setFilters(array('password', 'credit_card'));
```